# How to find the location of a scripted / advanced reference qualifier in servicenow?

Tags: javascript, reference, servicenow

In a variable set I see a reference qualifier. It's an advanced qualifier made in javascript. I searched in client scripts and various script includes, but I am unable to find that piece of code.
Of course I have the name and the name of the variable Set it appears it.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a *reference_qual* field you can execute javascript code by starting the value with:

```
javascript: <SCRIPT>
```

It is usually use to call a function which retrieves the filter or the sys_ids that the field or variable will apply, for example:

```
javascript: myFunction()
```

Those functions are executed on the server side, so in a well-design implementation they should be stored in a script include. Some legacy code could call a Business Rule declare for the Global table, so you should take a look also there (you can filter by those script includes / business rules which the field "script" contains "myFunction()").

If you paste the reference_qual content it will be easier to understand what it does.

Comment: Yes the function is a filter, but I wasnt able to find it in either script includes, nor business rules or client scripts. :/

Comment: In the end I found the script in the script includes, I filtered wrong :)